# Ember model to json

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am looking for an efficient way to translate my Ember object to a json string, to use it in a websocket message below

```
/*
 * Model
 */

App.node = Ember.Object.extend({
  name: 'theName',
  type: 'theType',
  value: 'theValue',
})
```

The websocket method:

```
App.io.emit('node', {node: hash});
```

hash should be the json representation of the node. {name: thename, type: theType, ..}
There must be a fast onliner to do this.. I dont want to do it manualy since i have many attributes and they are likely to change..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ember Data `Model`'s object counts with a `toJSON` method which optionally receives an plain object with `includeId` property used to convert an Ember Data Model into a JSON with the properties of the model.

https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/2.10/classes/DS.Model/methods/toJSON?anchor=toJSON

You can use it as follows:

```js
const objects = models.map((model) => model.toJSON({ includeId: true }));
```

Hope it helps. Enjoy!

Answer (score 14):

As stated you can take inspiration from the [ember-runtime/lib/core.js#inspect](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-runtime/lib/core.js#L290-308) function to get the keys of an object, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/UUusD/

```
App.Jsonable = Ember.Mixin.create({
    getJson: function() {
        var v, ret = [];
        for (var key in this) {
            if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                v = this[key];
                if (v === 'toString') {
                    continue;
                } // ignore useless items
                if (Ember.typeOf(v) === 'function') {
                    continue;
                }
                ret.push(key);
            }
        }
        return this.getProperties.apply(this, ret);
    }
});
```

Note, since commit [1124005](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/11240056d8f572f1860966da3b13431d85f5b64c) - which is available in `ember-latest.js` and in the next release - you can pass the `ret` array directly to `getProperties`, so the return statement of the `getJson` function looks like this:

```
return this.getProperties(ret);
```

Comment: To get this working in IE8, I had to add another guardian if:
if (key.indexOf('__ember') !== -1) {
  continue;
}

Comment: This doesn't seem to support nested hierarchies of Jsonables

Answer (score 11):

You can get a plain JS object (or hash) from an `Ember.Object` instance by calling `getProperties()` with a list of keys.

If you want it as a string, you can use `JSON.stringify()`.

For example:

```
var obj  = Ember.Object.create({firstName: 'Erik', lastName: 'Bryn', login: 'ebryn'}),
    hash = obj.getProperties('firstName', 'lastName'), // => {firstName: 'Erik', lastName: 'Bryn'}
    stringHash = JSON.stringify(hash); // => '{"firstName": "Erik", "lastName": "Bryn"}'
```

Comment: What if you want to get all properties out of the Ember model? obj.getProperties() doesn't work. is there any easy way other than to list all properties. That would be tedious if there are too many properties in the model.

Comment: There isn't a way, other than using `Object.keys` to extract all the properties out of an Ember object. You have to know what properties you're using.

Comment: You could take some inspiration from `Ember.inspect`, see https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-runtime/lib/core.js#L290-308

Answer (score 4):

I have also been struggling with this. As Mirko says, if you pass the ember object to JSON.stringify you will get circular reference error. However if you store the object inside one property and use stringify on that object, it works, even nested subproperties.

```
var node = Ember.Object.create({
  data: {
    name: 'theName',
    type: 'theType',
    value: 'theValue'
  }
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(node.get('data')));
```

However, this only works in Chrome, Safari and Firefox. In IE8 I get a stack overflow so this isn't a viable solution.

I have resorted to creating JSON schemas over my object models and written a recursive function to iterate over the objects using the properties in the schemas and then construct pure Javascript objects which I can then stringify and send to my server. I also use the schemas for validation so this solution works pretty well for me but if you have very large and dynamic data models this isn't possible. I'm also interested in simpler ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4):

I modifed @pangratz solution slightly to make it handle nested hierarchies of Jsonables:

```
App.Jsonable = Ember.Mixin.create({
    getJson: function() {
        var v, json = {};
        for (var key in this) {
            if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                v = this[key];
                if (v === 'toString') {
                    continue;
                } 
                if (Ember.typeOf(v) === 'function') {
                    continue;
                }
                if (App.Jsonable.detect(v))
                    v = v.getJson();
                json[key] = v;
            }
        }
        return json;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`App.io.emit('node', {node: node.toJSON()});`

Or if you have an ID property and want to include it:

`App.io.emit('node', {node: node.toJSON({includeId: true})});`

Comment: it is year ago i asked this question so I asume this is how things are done now..

Answer (score 2):

Will this work for you?

```
var json = JSON.stringify( Ember.getMeta( App.node, 'values') );
```

The `false` is optional, but would be more performant if you do not intend to modify any of the properties, which is the case according to your question.  This works for me, but I am wary that Ember.meta is a private method and may work differently or not even be available in future releases.  (Although, it isn't immediately clear to me if Ember.getMeta() is private).  You can view it in its latest source form here:

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-metal/lib/utils.js

The `values` property contains only 'normal' properties.  You can collect any cached, computed properties from `Ember.meta( App.node, false ).cached`.  So, provided you use jQuery with your build, you can easily merge these two objects like so:

```
$.extend( {}, Ember.getMeta(App.node, 'values'), Ember.getMeta(App.node, 'cache') );
```

Sadly, I haven't found a way to get sub-structures like array properties in this manner.

Answer (score 2):

I've written an extensive article on how you can convert ember models into native objects or JSON which may help you or others :)

<s>http://pixelchild.com.au/post/44614363941/how-to-convert-ember-objects-to-json</s>

http://byronsalau.com/blog/convert-ember-objects-to-json/

Comment: Sites back up @KevinPauli - my DNS went down for a while annoyingly.

Comment: ah ok.  editing the post so I can undo my downvote.  I must have been in a really bad mood that day, sorry

Comment: it is telling me I can't undo my downvote unless the anser is edited in some way.  I submitted an edit but it hasn't been approved.  If you'll edit it I will undo the downvote

Comment: @KevinPauli edited :) No dramas if you dont get to it, dosnt bother me.

Answer (score 1):

I modified @Kevin-pauli solution to make it works with arrays as well:

```
App.Jsonable = Ember.Mixin.create({
    getJson: function() {
        var v, json = {}, inspectArray = function (aSome) {
            if (Ember.typeof(aSome) === 'array') {
                return aSome.map(inspectArray);
            }
            if (Jsonable.detect(aSome)) {
                return aSome.getJson();
            } 
            return aSome;
        };
        for (var key in this) {
            if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                v = this[key];
                if (v === 'toString') {
                    continue;
                } 
                if (Ember.typeOf(v) === 'function') {
                    continue;
                }
                if (Ember.typeOf(v) === 'array') {
                    v = v.map(inspectArray);
                }
                if (App.Jsonable.detect(v))
                    v = v.getJson();
                json[key] = v;
            }
        }
        return json;
    }
});
```

I also made some further modification to get the best of both worlds. With the following version I check if the Jsonable object has a specific property that informs me on which of its properties should be serialized:

```
App.Jsonable = Ember.Mixin.create({
    getJson: function() {
        var v, json = {}, base, inspectArray = function (aSome) {
            if (Ember.typeof(aSome) === 'array') {
                return aSome.map(inspectArray);
            }
            if (Jsonable.detect(aSome)) {
                return aSome.getJson();
            } 
            return aSome;
        };
        if (!Ember.isNone(this.get('jsonProperties'))) {
            // the object has a selective list of properties to inspect
            base = this.getProperties(this.get('jsonProperties'));
        } else {
            // no list given: let's use all the properties
            base = this;
        }
        for (var key in base) {
            if (base.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                v = base[key];
                if (v === 'toString') {
                    continue;
                } 
                if (Ember.typeOf(v) === 'function') {
                    continue;
                }
                if (Ember.typeOf(v) === 'array') {
                    v = v.map(inspectArray);
                }
                if (App.Jsonable.detect(v))
                    v = v.getJson();
                json[key] = v;
            }
        }
        return json;
    }
});
```

I am using this little tweak and I am happy with it. I hope it'll help others as well!

Thanks to @pangratz and @Kevin-Pauli for their solution!

Answer (score 1):

Here I take @leo, @pangratz and @kevin-pauli solution a little step further. Now it iterates not only with arrays but also through **has many** relationships, it doesn't check if a value has the type **Array** but it calls the **isArray** function defined in Ember's API.

**Coffeescript**

```
App.Jsonable = Em.Mixin.create
  getJson: ->
    jsonValue = (attr) ->
      return attr.map(jsonValue) if Em.isArray(attr)
      return attr.getJson() if App.Jsonable.detect(attr)
      attr
    base =
      if Em.isNone(@get('jsonProperties'))
        # no list given: let's use all the properties
        this
      else
        # the object has a selective list of properties to inspect
        @getProperties(@get('jsonProperties'))
    hash = {}
    for own key, value of base
      continue if value is 'toString' or Em.typeOf(value) is 'function'
      json[key] = jsonValue(value)
    json
```

**Javascript**

```
var hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty;

App.Jsonable = Em.Mixin.create({
  getJson: function() {
    var base, hash, hashValue, key, value;
    jsonValue = function(attr) {
      if (Em.isArray(attr)) {
        return attr.map(jsonValue);
      }
      if (App.Jsonable.detect(attr)) {
        return attr.getJson();
      }
      return attr;
    };
    base = Em.isNone(this.get('jsonProperties')) ? this : this.getProperties(this.get('jsonProperties'));
    json = {};
    for (key in base) {
      if (!hasProp.call(base, key)) continue;
      value = base[key];
      if (value === 'toString' || Em.typeOf(value) === 'function') {
        continue;
      }
      json[key] = jsonValue(value);
    }
    return json;
  }
});
```

Comment: add "var" in front of json. proposed a change

Answer (score 0):

I have:

- fixed and simplified code
- added circular reference prevention
- added use of get of value
- removed all of the default properties of an empty component

  ```
  //Modified by Shimon Doodkin 
  //Based on answers of: @leo, @pangratz, @kevin-pauli, @Klaus
  //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669340

  App.Jsonable = Em.Mixin.create({
      getJson : function (keysToSkip, visited) {
          //getJson() called with no arguments,
          // they are to pass on values during recursion.

          if (!keysToSkip)
              keysToSkip = Object.keys(Ember.Component.create());

          if (!visited)
              visited = [];

          visited.push(this);

          var getIsFunction;

          var jsonValue = function (attr, key, obj) {
              if (Em.isArray(attr))
                  return attr.map(jsonValue);
              if (App.Jsonable.detect(attr))
                  return attr.getJson(keysToSkip, visited);
              return getIsFunction?obj.get(key):attr;
          };

          var base;
          if (!Em.isNone(this.get('jsonProperties')))
              base = this.getProperties(this.get('jsonProperties'));
          else
              base = this;

          getIsFunction=Em.typeOf(base.get) === 'function';

          var json = {};

          var hasProp = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;

          for (var key in base) {

              if (!hasProp.call(base, key) || keysToSkip.indexOf(key) != -1)
                  continue;

              var value = base[key];

              // there are usual circular references
              // on keys: ownerView, controller, context === base

              if ( value === base ||
                   value === 'toString' ||
                   Em.typeOf(value) === 'function')
                  continue;

              // optional, works also without this,
              // the rule above if value === base covers the usual case
              if (visited.indexOf(value) != -1)
                  continue;

              json[key] = jsonValue(value, key, base);

          }

          visited.pop();
          return json;
      }
  });

  /*
  example:

  DeliveryInfoInput = Ember.Object.extend(App.Jsonable,{
   jsonProperties: ["title","value","name"], //Optionally specify properties for json
   title:"",
   value:"",
   input:false,
   textarea:false,
   size:22,
   rows:"",
   name:"",
   hint:""
  })
  */
  ```

Answer (score -3):

Ember.js appears to have a JSON library available. I hopped into a console (Firebug) on one the Todos example and the following worked for me:

```
hash = { test:4 }
JSON.stringify(hash)
```

So you should be able to just change your line to

```
App.io.emit('node', { node:JSON.stringify(hash) })
```

Comment: I think Stephan's challenge lies in obtaining the hash representation that can then be passed to JSON.stringify. Passing the actual Ember object doesn't work (I'm getting an error about circular structure). Digging through the Ember source, I haven't been able to find a built-in way to convert an Ember object to a hash, so you may need to implement this manually for your object.

Comment: @MirkoFroehlich - Ah, gotcha. I guess I read it to hastily :-)