# How do you serialise Ember objects?

Tags: serialization, deserialization, ember.js

I need to use localStorage to store some Ember objects. I notice that Ember objects have properties with names like `__ember1334992182483`. When I call `JSON.stringify()` on Ember objects, these `__ember*` properties are not serialised. Why is this? I'm not saying that I want to serialize those properties. I am just curious about what exactly they are and how they are implemented such that they are not serialised.

I am using cycle.js (https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/cycle.js) to encode my data structures that contain duplicate references into a string that can be used for reconstructing the original data structures. It lets you do this:

```
a = {a:1}
b = {b:1}
c = [[a, b], [b, a]]

foo = JSON.stringify(JSON.decycle(c))  // "[[{'a':1},{'b':1}],[{'$ref':'$[0][1]'},{'$ref':'$[0][0]'}]]"
JSON.retrocycle(JSON.parse(foo))  // reconstruct c
```

For Ember objects I can do the same thing, but I also need to pass the deserialised objects into `Ember.Object.create()` because they are deserialised as plain JavaScript objects.

Is this the best way to serialise/deserialise Ember objects? Is there a recommended technique for this?

Answer (score 8):

For serialization and deserialization you could do something along this lines, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/NVpng/:

```js
App.Serializable = Ember.Mixin.create({
    serialize: function() {
        var propertyNames = this.get('propertyNames') || [];
        return this.getProperties(propertyNames);
    },

    deserialize: function(hash) {
        this.setProperties(hash);
    }
});

App.Person = Ember.Object.extend(App.Serializable, {
    propertyNames: 'firstName title fullName'.w(),
    fullName: function() {
        return '%@ %@'.fmt(this.get('title'), this.get('firstName'));
    }.property('firstName', 'title')
});

var hansi = App.Person.create({
    firstName: 'Hansi',
    title: 'Mr.'
});

// { firstName: 'hansi', title: 'Mr.', fullName: 'Mr. Hansi' }
console.log( hansi.serialize() );

var hubert = App.Person.create();
hubert.deserialize({
    firstName: 'Hubert',
    title: 'Mr.'
});
console.log( hubert.serialize() );​
```

---

**UPDATE**: Also have a look at the similar question [Ember model to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669340/ember-model-to-json)

Comment: Why are the `__ember*` properties not in the output of `JSON.stringify()`?

Comment: I have to guess here since I'm not a JavaScript expert: but if you do a `for (prop in obj) {}` on an `Ember.Object`, no `__ember*` is listed and a check for `obj.hasOwnProperty` only returns true for the defined properties, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/w53DH/.

Comment: The `__ember*` properties do not get listed in the `for...in` loop. Doing `App.obj.hasOwnProperty('__ember1335029966963')` returns `true`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use ember-data and write a datastore adapter for this.

Answer (score 0):

I have:

- fixed and simplified code
- added circular reference prevention
- added use of get of value
- removed all of the default properties of an empty component

  ```
  //Modified by Shimon Doodkin 
  //Based on answers of: @leo, @pangratz, @kevin-pauli, @Klaus
  //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669340

  App.Jsonable = Em.Mixin.create({
      getJson : function (keysToSkip, visited) {
          //getJson() called with no arguments,
          // they are to pass on values during recursion.

          if (!keysToSkip)
              keysToSkip = Object.keys(Ember.Component.create());

          if (!visited)
              visited = [];

          visited.push(this);

          var getIsFunction;

          var jsonValue = function (attr, key, obj) {
              if (Em.isArray(attr))
                  return attr.map(jsonValue);
              if (App.Jsonable.detect(attr))
                  return attr.getJson(keysToSkip, visited);
              return getIsFunction?obj.get(key):attr;
          };

          var base;
          if (!Em.isNone(this.get('jsonProperties')))
              base = this.getProperties(this.get('jsonProperties'));
          else
              base = this;

          getIsFunction=Em.typeOf(base.get) === 'function';

          var json = {};

          var hasProp = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;

          for (var key in base) {

              if (!hasProp.call(base, key) || keysToSkip.indexOf(key) != -1)
                  continue;

              var value = base[key];

              // there are usual circular references
              // on keys: ownerView, controller, context === base

              if ( value === base ||
                   value === 'toString' ||
                   Em.typeOf(value) === 'function')
                  continue;

              // optional, works also without this,
              // the rule above if value === base covers the usual case
              if (visited.indexOf(value) != -1)
                  continue;

              json[key] = jsonValue(value, key, base);

          }

          visited.pop();
          return json;
      }
  });

  /*
  example:

  DeliveryInfoInput = Ember.Object.extend(App.Jsonable,{
   jsonProperties: ["title","value","name"], //Optionally specify properties for json
   title:"",
   value:"",
   input:false,
   textarea:false,
   size:22,
   rows:"",
   name:"",
   hint:""
  })
  */
  ```