# How to console my ember models as json values?

Tags: json, ember.js

I would like to console all my `model's` current satus before i proceed to next router. for that, I am trying to check the status of my `model`. I tried like this  form the suggession of this quesiton:[Ember model to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669340/ember-model-to-json)

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        proceed: function() {
            this.set('clickCancel',false);
        },

        formValidateBeforeNext:function(){
            console.log("i am called", this.getProperties(ret) );
        }
    }
});
```

But not works!!

**UPDATE:**

I tried to console `models` as this way still not works.

import Ember from 'ember';

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        proceed: function() {
            this.set('clickCancel',false);
        },

        formValidateBeforeNext:function(){
            var rect = {};
            var propertyNames = arguments;
            if (arguments.length === 1 && Ember.typeOf(arguments[0]) === 'array') {
                propertyNames = arguments[0];
            }

             for(var i = 0; i < propertyNames.length; i++) {
                ret[propertyNames[i]] = get(this, propertyNames[i]);
            }

            console.log( "rect is",  rect );
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: How about `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ret))` ?

Comment: @kumkanillam Sure, let me try and let you know. but can you share me the correct way? is my 1 try or 2 try which one is correct?

Comment: I dont know what is `ret` in `this.getProperties(ret)`? it should be array of property name. then it  will work

Comment: if you don't mind, can you share me a `ember-twiddle` if possible get console the `model` in route?

Answer (score 1):

I see a typo in your example...
`ret[propertyNames[i]] = get(this, propertyNames[i]);`
should be ...
`rect[propertyNames[i]] = get(this, propertyNames[i]);`