# Set model not consoled by JSON stringify - what is wrong?

Tags: ember.js, ember-model

I am setting some value to `model` like :

```
afterModel:function(model,transation){
        Ember.set(model, 'processedTrans', 'TechMahindra');
    },
```

when i require the value I used to get : `model.get('processedTrans')` - works fine. But in case if I do:

`JSON.stringify(model)` - I am not finding the value what i set in the `afterModel` method. what is the issue here? or do i require to add any additional stuff to get in `json` string? Really what i set is my `models` property?

any one help me to understand this?

Comment: shouldn't it be `model.set('processedTrans', 'TechMahindra')` ?

Comment: If so how can I getting value?

Comment: Ember twiddle to will help us to understand your issue better. https://ember-twiddle.com

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669340/ember-model-to-json)